# General solutions of the fields in a charge free system

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential, terminology

In Electrodynamics, What do we mean by **general solutions of the fields in a charge free system**?

Comment: Do you have the context for this statement? That would really help answer this.

Comment: General solution sometimes refers to the solution when no boundary conditions are enforced. In that case the solution is **parameterized**.

Comment: I mean where is this statement coming from?